# Resolving OpenWrap error:- Missing values for the following command inputs: Href

Tags: openwrap

I'm trying to set up my own http openwrap repository. I've read https://github.com/openrasta/openwrap/wiki/Openwrap-publishing-protocol but didn't understand much of it. Then I found http://olsonjeffery.github.com/infrastructure/tooling/.NET/2011/02/01/Deployment-with-OpenWrap.html, in which the author explains (not very clearly) how to do it.

So I took the following approach:

1. Follow the instructions on http://www.anthonysteele.co.uk/how-to-package-up-files-with-openwrap to create a local repository
2. Create a site (IIS7 Web Server) and add a virtual directory called **openwraprepository**, pointing it to the local repository folder
3. Ensure that directory browsing is on and that you can get to a file called **index.wraplist** with a browser
4. Add the **mime-types** for *.wraplist* (application/oebps-package+xml) and *.wrap* (application/vnd.openwrap.package)

Now, from the package on my development machine I should be able to specify this as a repository by typing **o add-remote http://mysite/openwraprepository**.

I get the following error:
**Missing values for the following command inputs: Href**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the openwrap publishing protocol is for openwrap 2.0, and is a set of modular features you can add on top of a simple indexed repository like the one described in that blog. (We need to add those steps to the documentation, I think that'd be useful :))

As for adding it, if you look at the get-help section on add-remote, you'll see that you need two inputs, -name and -href. You provided one but not the other.

```
o add-remote myRemote http://mysite/openwraprepository
```

That should then let you do just what you want.